# Behavior of update with left join

Tags: mysql, sql-update, left-join, mariadb

Using mysql 5.5, a statement like this:

```
update foo left join bar on foo.id=bar.id set foo.col='val', bar.col='val';
```

does appear to update foo rows even when there is no bar (and the bar.col= does not generate any errors or warnings).  But as far as I can see, this is not guaranteed in the mysql documentation.

Can anyone provide an authoritative reference, either in an SQL standard or from Oracle, stating this is intentional?

Does it work the same in other flavors of SQL, particularly <strike>postgres and</strike> MariaDB, or other versions of mysql?

Note that the following, unlike the above, does have the left join promoted to an inner join:

```
update foo left join bar on foo.id=bar.id set bar.col='val';
```

but this may be simply an optimization.

Update: to clarify, the behavior I see is the behavior I want; I am just concerned that it appears to me to be undocumented.  If I wanted an inner join, I would use one.

Comment: You can't alter the question after answers have been given in a way that would make legit answers seem off topic. I rolled back your last edit.

Comment: Nobody so far has answered my actual question, though you have clarified for me that it doesn't apply at all to PostgreSQL, which I appreciate.  IMO leaving the mention of postgres struck out is amply sufficient to justify your having given your answer; I'm putting it back (and upvoting your answer).

Comment: Well, the comments serve to clarify. Generally, changing the nature of a question in a way that would invalidate given answers is a no-go.

Comment: Doesn't `For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions.` from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html page guarantee this functionality for you?

Comment: @AgRizzo: almost, but not quite

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, this odd kind of syntax is simply invalid. An [`UPDATE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) only ever changes data in a *single* table directly (except with inheritance).
You would use instead:

```
UPDATE foo
SET    col = 'val'
FROM   bar
WHERE  foo.id = bar.id;
```

Or, since you are using a constant value, this faster form:

```
UPDATE foo
SET    col = 'val'
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   bar
   WHERE  foo.id = bar.id
   );
```

.. which should work in *any* of the named RDMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...).

Either of these queries *only* updates rows of `foo` where a match is found in `bar`. Often, it is wise to add:

```
AND col IS DISTINCT FROM 'val'
```

Or:

```
AND col <> 'val'                  -- if involved values are NOT NULL
```

.. to avoid empty updates.

Comment: thanks, this makes it clear my question doesn't apply at all to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

It's a left join, so what you're seeing is expected.

- `A cross join B` means: every A combined with every B — as in cartesian product.
- `A inner join B`, or simply `A join B`, means: every A and B combined where there is an A *and* a B — as in, *mandatory have both A and B*.
- `A left join B` means: every A where there is no B, and every A and B combined where there is an A and a B — as in, *B optional*.
- `A right join B` is equivalent to `B left join A`.
- `A full join B` means: every A where there is no B, every B where there is no A, and every A and B when they can be combined — as in, A *and* B optional.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Your second query updates the same `bar` rows as the first query. The only difference with the first one is that you're no longer updating `foo`, so you're possibly not seeing the same affected row count. You're only updating `bar` when there's an associated `foo`, but note that the query still shovels through `foo` rows that have no `bar` associated with them.

Answering the other part of your question: yes, other database engines behave the same way, give or take cosmetics related to syntax highlighted by Erwin. The gist of an update statement amounts to pseudocode that would read like: `for each row in (select … from …) do stuff`. The table in `update table` is the first in the associated `select … from … [join …]` statement that gets run.

Comment: so why doesn't `bar.col='val'` make bar non-optional in the first case?

Comment: @ysth: my bad, I had missed the `set` statement. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the first part of my question, it just describes the behavior I already see.  thanks anyway.

Comment: @ysth: I'm not sure what more you'd want for the first part of your question… It's a simple explanation of how joins work. Or did you merely want a [wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) and an [oracle reference](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ansi-iso-sql-support.php) on ANSI joins?

Comment: What does the presence of a set col= for a column of a table that is only left joined?  I like the behavior I see, but I could argue that it *should* make the left join effectively an inner join, or generate a warning, or even an error.  I'm not asking for an explanation, I'm asking for documentation that the existing behavior is in fact guaranteed.

Comment: Trouble is, the ansi sql standard itself is not openly available for reading. :-( I vaguely recollect seeing a link towards a draft of it on postgresql.org somewhere, but I'm at a loss as to how to locate it after a few cursory searches. This much I can guarantee you, though: your `update foo left join bar set …` is merely syntactic sugar around what amounts to `update x set … from (select foo left join bar …) x`; so yes, it is indeed guaranteed in the sense that you're asking… in mysql anyway, and mariadb (which is still equivalent), though not in Postgres since it'll reject the syntax.

Comment: no, it isn't just syntactic sugar; postgres will *not* update more than one table.  So I suspect the SQL standard doesn't even address this (though I hadn't originally suspected that)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my comment. Yes, that MySQL allows to change rows from more than one table is an oddity in the SQL world. But the fact remains that when you run the more standard `update foo from bar …` the generated query tree is the exact same one as when you run `select foo join bar …`. The only difference is that instead of outputting the rows, you update them; if you run `explain analyze` in Postgres, you'll merely see an extra `update on` step. In this sense, it's merely syntactic sugar per my above comment.